# NASM can't launch

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I installed NASM via the NASM.us site but it just won't launch. I'm on Windows 11 and i tried installing via CMD, stopping my anti-virus, installing the .zip file but just wont launch. Please help because i don't want to use Visual Studio code for writing in assembly x86.

Comment: How does it not launch? Did you open a command window, navigated to the folder and run `nasm.exe`?

Comment: Yes, I launched the `nasm.exe` program. I oppen a CMD window but then close immediatly.

Comment: You should open the cmd window and launch nasm from there. The way I understand you just clicked on nasm.exe which of course exits immediately so that's normal.

Comment: `nasm` takes command-line args to tell it what file to assemble, and into what format.  Double-clicking on it won't pass any.